# How to call jquery functions for the dynamically added control using Ajax.ActionLink

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am generating a group of controls(3 dropdownlist,1 textbox & a label) using Ajax.Actionlink & Partial view.The ist dropdownlist has been populated with the content of the Viewbag that has been passed in the partial view, but content of 2nd dropdown depends on the selection of 1st dropdown list & same for 3rd dropdown list(Depends upon the selection of 2nd dropdown list). I am making an ajax call through the jquery  to populate the 2 lists(2nd & 3rd). I just want to know how to call the jquery function for these controls(for dropdownlist).

Here is My Controller

```
using System;  
using System.Collections.Generic;  
using System.Linq;  
using System.Web; 
using System.Web.Mvc;  
using My_Inventory.Models;

$message = "";
if (empty($_POST['first_name'])) {
    $message. = "First name required <br/>";
}
if (empty($_POST['last_name'])) {
    $message. = "Last name required";
    if ($message) {
        echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>".$message.
        "</div>";
    } else {
        // write to db, send email etc.
```

My Partial View, the one i am using with Ajax.Actionlink

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>Select Category</th> 
    <th>Select SubCategory</th>
    <th>Select Product</th>
    <th>Enter Quantity</th>
    <th>Cost</th>   
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DropDownList("Category", ViewBag.Category as SelectList, "Select", new {@id = "ddlSelect",onchange = "Getoption();" })

     </td>
    <td>@Html.DropDownList("SubCategory", new SelectList(Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "Value", "Text"), "Select", new { @id = "ddlsub", onchange = "GetProducts();" })</td>
    <td>@Html.DropDownList("Products", new SelectList(Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "Value", "Text"), "Select", new { @id = "ddlProduct" })</td>
    <td>@Html.TextBox("Quantity", "", new { @id = "TextQuantity", onblur = "Calculatecost();" })</td>
    <td>@Html.Label("Cost", "Amount", new { @id = "TotalCost" })</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

& My Jquery functions that i want to use to populate dropdownlists with Options.

```
$message = "";
if (empty($_POST['first_name'])) {
    $message. = "First name required <br/>";
}
if (empty($_POST['last_name'])) {
    $message. = "Last name required";
    if ($message) {
        echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>".$message.
        "</div>";
    } else {
        // write to db, send email etc.
```

I just want to use these two functions in the dynamically Added Controls..
Please suggest..

Answer (score 0):

use 
   `$("body").on("Categody","change",Getoption());` instead of
   `$("Category").on("change", Getoption())`